# Got 2 Ethernets one on WAN the other LAN. but LAN Could not resolve hostname

Tags: hostname

I keep getting **Could not resolve hostname** but I can put in the IP and it works.

I could not open the port to WWW on my LAN so just using a router and it gets on like that. Then another router for my lAN with the other Ethernet.

How can I fix this so I can get use the hose name of other LAN servers?

-Raymond Day

Comment: When are you getting Could not resolve hostname? Does `ping cloudflare.com` work? Does `ping 1.1.1.1` (Cloudflare's DNS server) work? What type of hostname are you trying to ping? `.local` ones tend to not work super well

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please [edit] your question to add information, comments are an "Us to You" channel, used to help you make your question better, and more likely to receive an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the Ethernet config from a new load on a unit that had 2 ethernet ports that fix it.

=Raymond Day